# Comparing the magnitude of coefficients for two different logistic regression models

Tags: r, regression, logistic, standardization

I have built two logistic regression models for two different groups and I want to make comparisons between them. Both models have had their features standardized with mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1. Is it theoretically correct to compare the magnitudes of the coefficients of both models?

I have read through Allison's report ([Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245713924_Comparing_Logit_and_Probit_Coefficients_Across_Groups/citations)), but I do not quite understand the theory and whether it will apply to the case where the features are standardized.

If I can be pointed in the right direction it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why standardize the variables?  And did you use the same standard deviation for both groups?  If not that will make comparisons very difficult.   Results are easier to interpret if you do not standardize, and that also allows you to assess group $\times X$ interaction.

Comment: The variables were standardized so that the sample variances are then all equal to 1. This will not affect the overall properties of the models, and I am able to compare the magnitude of the coefficients of the two different models. This was my understanding but I may be incorrect.

Comment: I believe what @Frank is reacting to is that the standardization, which in effect changes the units of measurement of variables, will be different for the two groups.  This makes it difficult to make any meaningful comparisons. If you must standardize, then at least consider using identical transformations for both groups.  For instance, adjoin all the data, standardize all features, then split them back into two separate datasets.  It would be simpler, though, to fit a single model on all the data, using the group identifier as a covariate.